# Need help with Inherit Time Machine backup on Big Sur

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, backup, time-machine, big-sur

Quick explainer guys.

I used a 2015 MacBook 12", battery was dead, bought a 2015 MacBook Pro 15. Migrated everything directly from one Mac to another over Wi-Fi with Migration Assistant (worked surprisingly well).

I also have an older drive with my Time Machine backups going back to like 2021 which I've used before on that older Macbook 12" when the battery was still working and I could connect an external drive to it.

So, on my TimeMachine drive I now have in `/Volumes/Time Machine/Backups.backupdb/Macbook` several folders.

I really want to inherit this backup and continue to use it. HOWEVER. Stupid Big Sur doesn't allow me to do so.

I've tried the usual `sudo tmutil inheritbackup`, few times got errors, also tried `associate`, today tried `inherit` again - seems like it didn't spit out any errors. BUT.

When I started making a backup instead of changing the name from `Macbook` to `MacBook Pro` and continuing to make a backup into an already existing folder, Time Machine created a new folder called `MacBook Pro` and tried to create a **full new** backup there, which is exactly something that I'm trying to avoid.

Not least, because I don't have enough space on that drive, but also because I would like to preserve the history of the backups just in case.

My question is: what can I do, is this normal?
I think I've read somewhere that if I set up my new Mac with that Migration Assistance Time Machine will refuse to inherit the backup and will always try to create the full new one. Is that true? Can anyone confirm?

Is this because the names of the Macs are different - one is `Macbook` and another `MacBook Pro`? Please, someone help, I've already wasted two days trying to figure out this crap and I'm still totally SOL

Just for clarity, previously I've used macOS Mojave 10.14.6 (and loved it), and now it's Big Sur 11.7.10. Can this problem occur because of this?